# How to open crystal report using jquery to prevent postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, crystal-reports

We have application where we have created all the save update and delete code using Jquery to prevent post-back. But now we are facing issue while opening crystal report. 
We tried to find out similar code on internet but could not.

We are not able to pass crystal report viewer id in web method from ASPX page.

Please find Below jquery Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#btnprint").click(function () {
               var param = { grpval1: $('#txtbatchid').val() };
               $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
                   url: "frmelectbatchdsptch.aspx/PrintData",
                   data: JSON.stringify(param),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (data) {

                   }
                   //
               });
           })
       });
</script>
```

Please find below [Web Method], which we have used to open crystal report.

```
[Web Method]
       public static void PrintData(string grpval1)
       {
           //public static string PrintData(string param)
           //{
           SqlConnection sqlcon = new DBConnection().testconnection();
           DBConnection objmain = new DBConnection();
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           saveData cust = new saveData();
           String data = "Sp_Electdsptchprint'" + grpval1 + "','" + cust.strfinancialyr + "','" + cust.strbranchname + "','" + cust.strfcompid + "'";
           dt = objmain.Databaseselection(data);
           ReportDocument rptdoc = new ReportDocument();
           rptdoc.Load(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Reports/Electdsptchprint.rpt"));
           rptdoc.SetDataSource(dt);
           rptdoc.SetParameterValue("@txtbatchid", grpval1);
           rptdoc.SetParameterValue("@finyearid", cust.strfinancialyr);
           rptdoc.SetParameterValue("@branchid1", cust.strbranchname);
           rptdoc.SetParameterValue("@CompanyID", cust.strfcompid);
           //string Reporttitle = Request.QueryString["Reporttitle"];
           //rptdoc.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = Reporttitle;
           string GserverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GserverName"];
           string GDbUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GDbUser"];
           string GDbpwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GDbpwd"];
           string GDbname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GDbname"];
           rptdoc.SetDatabaseLogon(GDbUser, GDbpwd, GserverName, GDbname, false);
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
           {
               Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
               CrystalReportViewer cry = (CrystalReportViewer)page.FindControl("CrystalReportViewer1");
               cry.ReportSource = rptdoc;
               cry.DataBind();
           }
           CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptdoc;
           ConnectionInfo cnnInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
           cnnInfo.ServerName = GserverName;
           cnnInfo.DatabaseName = GDbname;
           cnnInfo.UserID = GDbUser;
           cnnInfo.Password = GDbpwd;

           foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbl in rptdoc.Database.Tables)
           {

               TableLogOnInfo tli = tbl.LogOnInfo;
               tli.ConnectionInfo = cnnInfo;
               tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(tli);
           }
           Session["Report"] = rptdoc;
       }
```

Below Error we are getting

Object reference not set to an instance of object

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
iCanopus Technology

Comment: when i go to restaurant, i found a mountain.

Comment: Will you please detail you problem? where is you code detail? where are you getting error exactly ?

Comment: Apologies... I have added script code and webmethod..